# git: почему все время "всплывают" игнорируемые файлы?

Tags: git, gitignore

В папке находится .gitignore с содержимым

```
*
!.gitignore
```

и тем не менее, git отслеживает изменения в этой папке.
После того, как я выполняю

```
cd dir
git update-index --assume-unchanged $(git ls-files | tr '\n' ' ')
```

содержимое этой папки пропадает из `git status`, но периодически появляется снова: например, после создания новой ветки. Почему так происходит?

Comment: к делу не относится, но `tr` в команде избыточен...

Comment: Дело в том, что файлы уже в репозитории, а игнорируемыми могут быть только не отслеживаемые файлы